# Рисование фигур в Pyside2

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, pyside2

Привожу код, который рисует точки и прямоугольники.

Фигуры, после отображение, исчезают. Почему фигуры исчезают?

Мне нужно отобразить несколько точек и прямоугольников в окне. Не могу разобраться как их сохранить.

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setGeometry(30,30,600,400)
    self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
    self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
    self.show()

def paintEvent(self, event):
    qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    br = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("transparent"))
    qp.setBrush(br)
    qp.drawRect(QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end))
    qp.end()

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.begin = event.pos()
    self.end = event.pos()
    self.update()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    self.end = event.pos()
    self.update()

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    self.begin = event.pos()
    self.end = event.pos()
    self.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWidget()
window.show()
app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея решения такова: когда мышь перемещается, пусть прямоугольник рисуется прямо в окне
(потому что вызов `self.update()` очистит содержимое окна и удалит неопределенный прямоугольник),
и мы определим его, когда мышь будет отпущена.

Код выглядит следующим образом:

1. В функции события отпускания мыши `mouseReleaseEvent()` мы создаем объект `QPainter`
   с холстом `self.pix` в качестве устройства рисования, а затем рисуем прямоугольник.
   В это время мышь была отпущена, и координаты были определены,
   поэтому может быть только один прямоугольник рисуется на холсте.
   После освобождения установите переменные `self.begin` и `self.end` в исходные координаты
   (то есть в значение null).
2. В функции события `paintEvent()` создайте экземпляр объекта `QPainter` с окном
   в качестве устройства рисования, а затем вызовите метод `drawPixmap()` для визуализации холста
   в окне.
3. Сначала определите, существуют ли `self.begin` и `self.end`
   (то есть определите, являются ли координаты обеими (0, 0)).
   Без этого предложения мы обнаружим, что точка рисуется в верхнем левом углу,
   когда мы запускаем программу.
   Затем вызовите метод `drawRect()`, чтобы нарисовать и удерживать его
   (здесь непосредственно рисуется в окне).

Измените импорты для PySide2 и попробуйте

```
import sys
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                      # PySide2
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                         # PyQt5


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.setGeometry(30,30,600,400)
        self.resize(600, 400)
        self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
#        self.show()

        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap(600, 400)                                    # +
        self.pix.fill(QtCore.Qt.white)                                        # +

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)                                              # 2
        qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.pix)        
        br = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("transparent"))
        qp.setBrush(br)
        if self.begin and self.end:                                            # 3
            rect = QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end)
            qp.drawRect(rect)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.begin = event.pos()
            self.end = self.begin
            self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.end = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):                                        # 1
#        self.begin = event.pos()
#        self.end = event.pos()
#        self.update()
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.pix)                                   
            rect = QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end)                           
            painter.drawRect(rect)                                            

            self.begin = self.end = QtCore.QPoint()                            # ... в значение null 
            self.update()                                                          
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
#    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы мне очень помогли! Благодарю Вас!

Comment: @Newman пожалуйста